# Select elements by data * attribute in CSS

Tags: css

I am pretty confident this is not possible. But how can I target all elements with a data attribute.

```
tr[data-*] //target all data's
```

Comment: I don't think is possible as far as i know with pure css.

Comment: Probably is possible but I'd struggle to find a use case for it.

Comment: I'd like to add cursors to all the elements that have a data attribute as they will be interactive.

Comment: have you looked at writing some javascript and targeting that way? Then at least you could specify empty and data accordingly, which would add a class on:hover?

Comment: hmmm...looks like you can only select by **specific** attributes...not generic ones. - http://jsfiddle.net/ngghf44x/

Comment: Not sure if this might help or not, but I think it could. Using **Multiple Attributes Values** http://css-tricks.com/multiple-attribute-values/, check fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/6DAwY/37/

Comment: Ye, I don't wan tto use js for this :) Far to much overhead for a simple thing.

Comment: you could give all those elements an additional common attribute and target that. `<tr data data-something="..">` and `<tr data data-other="">` and then target them with `tr[data]{..}`

Answer (score 0):

Neither the [**docs on Attribute Selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), or the [**docs on data attributes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) gives any example or a clue to a feature like this.

Instead it splicitly states that an attribute selector is composed by

> **[attr=value]**
>   [attr]
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr.

With variants in the equality comparision (such as "starts with", "ends with", etc) but only to the *value*, never on the `attr` name.

So, if your aim is to add a custom cursor to every `data-something` element, you'd need a different approach, maybe giving them specific classes.

Comment: Ye, thanks for clearling this up. I had wanted to avoid adding classes to every single data-* elements. Seems over kill for me :)